# MvvmCross MvxSpinner does not update after re-entering

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

**Resolved**

Please, I need some help!

Android Situation:

MSVisualStudio 2015 + Xamarin + Mvvmcross 4.4

One Activity and Several Fragments. Using default presenter.

1- View (Fragment) with MvxRecyclerView, a row is selected for editing.

2- Show new view (Fragment) with a MvxSpinner, and change its value (A) to another one (B). Remember: A & B are objects.

```
<Mvx.MvxSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_academic_start_week"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/spinner_basic"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_spinner_basic"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource AcademicYearWeeksCollection; SelectedItem AcademicStartWeek; HandleItemSelected SelectAcademicStartWeekCommand" />
```

and there is a ViewModel with

```
public IList<AcademicYearWeeks> AcademicYearWeeksCollection { get { return _academicYearWeeksCollection; } }
```

where *AcademicYearWeeks* is a class with properties and so on.

3- Cancel edition and return to View with MvxRecyclerView.

4- Repeat click for edit same row.

5- Oooppps! Spinner shows B not A. Why????

Other considerations:

Fragment with spinner always is called using

```
ShowViewModel<CourseViewModel>(
    new
     {
        courseId = item.CourseId
     });
```

and its ViewModel associated

```
public void Init(int courseId)
{
    _courseId = courseId;
}

public override void Start()
{
    base.Start();

    LoadAcademicYearWeeksCollection();

    if (_courseId == 0)
        NewCourse();
    else
        LoadCourse();
}
```

and is closed using

```
Close(this)
```

I'll be very greatful!

Thanks.

Comment: When you say show new view, is that a new fragment or activity or some other kind of view? are you saying that the state of the previous selection is remembered when return to the page with the spinner and you expect it to be a refresh reset page? How does your cancel flow work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a fragment using `MvxFragment` attribute, by default the `IsCacheableFragment` is set to true. Therefore, as the fragment and it ViewModel are being cached and you get the behaviour you are experiencing when returning to the page for a second time.

Ideally you should just be able to set the `IsCacheableFragment` to false

```
[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame,
    IsCacheableFragment = false)]
```

However, the behaviour of this feature is, I believe, undesired. As according to [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1371) it sets your ViewModel to null.

Another approach you can try it to force the fragment and ViewModel pair to refresh themselves. In your fragments parent activity override `ShowFragment` and set the `forceAddToBackStack` to true for your ViewModel with the spinner on it

```
protected override void ShowFragment(string tag, int contentId, Bundle bundle, bool forceAddToBackStack = false, bool forceReplaceFragment = false)
{
    if (tag.Equals(typeof(<<Your View Model Type>>).FullName))
        forceReplaceFragment = true;

    base.ShowFragment(tag, contentId, bundle, forceAddToBackStack, forceReplaceFragment);
}
```